# OpenCV decentralized processing for stereo vision

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a decent amount of experience with OpenCV and am currently familiarizing myself with stereo vision. I happen to have two [JeVois cameras](http://jevois.org/) (don't ask why) and was wondering if it was possible to run some sort of code on each camera to distribute the workload and cut down on processing time. It needs to be so that each camera can do part of the overall process (without needing to talk to each other) and the computer they're connected to receives that information and handles the rest of the work. If this is possible, does anyone have any solutions or tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `some sort of code on each camera to distribute the workload and cut down on processing time` which workload are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalize the stereo-vision pipeline (look [here](http://vision.deis.unibo.it/~smatt/Seminars/StereoVision.pdf) for more in-depth):

1. Find the intrinsic/extrinsic values of each camera [(good illustration here)](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#camera-calibration-and-3d-reconstruction)
2. Solve for the transformation that will rectify your cameras' images [(good illustration here)](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6320-S2012/Materials/CS6320-CV-F2012-Rectification.pdf)
3. Capture a pair of images
4. Transform the images according to Step 2.
5. Perform stereo-correspondence on that pair of rectified images

If we can assume that your cameras are going to remain perfectly stationary (relative to each other), you'll only need to perform Steps 1 and 2 one time after camera installation.

That leaves you with **image capture** (duh) and the **image rectification** as general stereo-vision tasks that can be done without the two cameras communicating.

Additionally, there are some pre-processing techniques (you could try [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/717d/efc1d7f67496e2f4770412eb3b096d46ed6a.pdf) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221625747_Enhanced_Real-time_Stereo_Using_Bilateral_Filtering)) that have been shown to improve the accuracy of some stereo-correspondence algorithms. These could also be done on each of your image-capture platforms individually.